# How can I grab the record set from a JOIN with the most recent datestamp?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am writing a stored procedure that is grabbing some data from 3 tables. Right now, my output looks like this:

[image: sql output]

Rig 20 is listed twice. I would like to grab only the record with the most recent datestamp. So my query now looks like this:

```
SELECT
      robinson_Rigs.rigId
    , robinson_Rigs.rigName
    , robinson_Clients.companyName
    , robinson_Wells.wellName
    , robinson_Wells.county
    , max(robinson_Wells.startDate)
    , robinson_Wells.directions
FROM robinson_Wells
    JOIN robinson_Rigs ON robinson_wells.rigId = robinson_Rigs.rigId
    JOIN robinson_Clients on robinson_Wells.clientId = robinson_Clients.clientId
group by robinson_Rigs.rigId
ORDER BY robinson_Rigs.rigId
```

But I am getting this error:

```
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Procedure robinson_GetAllDrivingDirections, Line 14
Column 'robinson_Rigs.rigName' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply grouping on everything but the StartDate will still return multiple rows for a rig if any other field contains a different value for the rig.

Instead, try something like this:

```
SELECT
      robinson_Rigs.rigId
    , robinson_Rigs.rigName
    , robinson_Clients.companyName
    , robinson_Wells.wellName
    , robinson_Wells.county
    , robinson_Wells.startDate
    , robinson_Wells.directions
FROM robinson_Wells
    JOIN robinson_Rigs ON robinson_wells.rigId = robinson_Rigs.rigId
    JOIN
    (
        SELECT rigId
            , MAX(startDate) AS MostRecentDate
        FROM robinson_rigs
        GROUP BY rigId
    ) latestRigDate ON robinson_Rigs.RigId = latestRigDate.RigId
        AND robinson_rigs.StartDate = latestRigDate.MostRecentDate
    JOIN robinson_Clients on robinson_Wells.clientId = robinson_Clients.clientId
ORDER BY robinson_Rigs.rigId
```

The joined subquery will return a list of all rig ids and their max (most recent) date.  Joining this to the complete robinson_rigs table by rigId and startDate will "filter" the table so that only records with the most recent date for each rig are returned.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
      robinson_Rigs.rigId
    , robinson_Rigs.rigName
    , robinson_Clients.companyName
    , robinson_Wells.wellName
    , robinson_Wells.county
    , max(robinson_Wells.startDate)
    , robinson_Wells.directions
FROM robinson_Wells
    JOIN robinson_Rigs ON robinson_wells.rigId = robinson_Rigs.rigId
    JOIN robinson_Clients on robinson_Wells.clientId = robinson_Clients.clientId
group by robinson_Rigs.rigId
    , robinson_Rigs.rigName
    , robinson_Clients.companyName
    , robinson_Wells.wellName
    , robinson_Wells.county
ORDER BY robinson_Rigs.rigId
```

group by everything before the aggregate. SQL does not play nice unless you understand the group by

Comment: This will still result in multiple records being returned for a single rig because `startDate` is not the only field whose value changes.  Any field in the `Group By` clause with a different value will cause an additional row to be returned.  I also believe this will return an error since 'directions' are not included in the group by (and the field also, at least in the example, contains a different value for each date, resulting in a second row being returned for rig 20).